# Copy and paste to sheet 2 based on column A conditional in sheet 1 not executing

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy and paste rows from sheet 1 (starting from row 2) to sheet 2 based on column A. Column A contains dates. I want to copy and paste rows over to sheet 2 if its greater than or equal to a certain date that I have in a cell on a different sheet. I ran the macro but it stops executing after the first instance. Any advice/guidance on how to resolve this issue is greatly appreciate.

```
Sub CopyRows()

    Dim MinDate As Date

    MinDate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet3").Cells(2, 124).Value

    lrow = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For I = 2 To lrow
        dest = Sheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(I, 1).Value >= MinDate Then
            Rows(I).Copy Sheets("sheet2").Rows(dest + 1)
        End If
    Next I

End Subl
```

Comment: It stops after the first instance of the date >= a certain date. So for example, I have two rows within the first column with 3/1/12. However, the code would only copy the first instance, not the second.

Comment: I just tested with multiple cells containing 3/1/12 and it's working OK.

Comment: Are you sure that Excel is seeing the values as dates and not text? Try coalescing both values and see if you get any errors: `If CDate(Cells(I, 1).Value) >= CDate(MinDate) Then`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear what you mean by "stops executing after the first instance."

If you mean the macro is copying the first row that is >= MinDate and then not copying any other rows, nothing in the subroutine you show would cause that. It does have some potential problems though.

The code is testing `Cells(I,1)` and copying `Rows(I)` on the `ActiveSheet`. If that sheet is not Sheet1 every time it tests a row, then it isn't testing or copying from the correct worksheet. You can fix that simply by explicitly stating which worksheet you are testing and copying from.

```
If Sheets("sheet1").Cells(I, 1).Value >= MinDate Then
    Sheets("sheet1").Rows(I).Copy Sheets("sheet2").Rows(dest + 1)
End If
```

I would actually re-write the routine to use the worksheet object. I've also included some status messages so you can see which rows are being copied.

```
Sub CopyRows()
    Dim MinDate As Date, lRow As Long, i As Integer, lDest As Long
    Dim shtFrom As Worksheet, shtTo As Worksheet

    Set shtFrom = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
    Set shtTo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2")

    MinDate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(2, 124).Value

    lRow = shtFrom.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lRow
        Application.StatusBar = "Row " & i & " of " & lRow
        lDest = shtTo.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        If shtFrom.Cells(i, 1).Value >= MinDate Then
            Application.StatusBar = Application.StatusBar & "  Copying..."
            shtFrom.Rows(i).Copy shtTo.Rows(lDest + 1)
        End If
    Next i
    Application.StatusBar = False

End Sub
```

If that is not the problem you are having, give us some more details.

If you don't know any more details, you can step thru your macro one line at a time by being in the macro on the VBA screen and pressing F8. While it is running in this way, if you put your mouse over a variable, it will tell you what it's current value is. You can do this to find out where in the code your problem is.